# How to construct several objects in one class, then read in another class

Tags: java, class, object, variables

I apologize if this is a basic question.

I am attempting to create several unique objects in one class, then get the values of one of the objects in another class.

I have created two classes and followed some examples to end with this

```
public class Type {
public String name;
public int healthmod;
public int strmod;
public int accmod;
public int armmod;
public int refmod;
public int intmod;
public String advantages;
public String disadvantages;

public Type() {
Type fire = new Type();
fire.name = "Fire";
fire.healthmod = 0;
fire.strmod = 1;
fire.accmod = 0;
fire.armmod = 0;
fire.refmod = 0;
fire.intmod = 1;
}
}
```

and then in the main class:

```
Player.typename = Type.fire.name;
```

**Edit**

```
    public class Player {
 public static String name, classname, racename, elementname;
 public static int maxhealth, healthpts, healthptscost, healthupgnum, healthmod, currenthealth, basehealth;
 public static int str, strpts, strptscost, strupgnum, strmod;
 public static int acc, accpts, accptscost, accupgnum, accmod;
 public static int arm, armpts, armptscost, armupgnum, armmod;
 public static int ref, refpts, refptscost, refupgnum, refmod;
 public static int intelligence, intpts, intptscost, intupgnum, intmod;
 public static int mana, maxmana, managain, managainak;
 public static int hitChance, critChance, Level, statPts, statTotal, damage, damageDealt, goldmult, itemmod, itemdefboost, itemdamboost, itemmodboost;
 public static String[] focusStats;
}
```

What I am trying to do is create a few objects in the Type class and access them in the Main class in order to store the values in the Player class, but in the Main class, fire "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

**Edited to provide more clarity on the purpose.**

Comment: Can you edit to provide your Player class also?

Comment: edited with player class

Answer (score 0):

You are completely mixing things here.

In the concstructor of Type you are creating a new local Object named fire. This object is only available in this constructor and not outside of it, e.g. in the main class.

A valid solution can only be found if you give more information about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to create several objects and then use the Main class to select one of the objects and pass the values to the Player class.

Again, I apologize if this is very basic question. I just started getting into Java again after more than 10 years.

Comment: Do you want to have some kind of constants that can be used later on?

Answer (score 0):

I could write like that your Type construct:

```
public Type() {
  this.name = "Fire";
  this.healthmod = 0;
  this.strmod = 1;
  this.accmod = 0;
  this.armmod = 0;
  this.refmod = 0;
  this.intmod = 1;
}
```

So when using the Player class in your Main method, like that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Type type = new Type();
  Player.typename = type.name;
}
```

You can also put a reference of type inside Player class like that:

```
public class Player {
  public static Type fire;
}
```

So in your main method like that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Player.fire = new Type();
  System.out.println(Player.fire.name);
}
```